# How to return newly inserted item(row) id using android room (Kotlin) on Compose?

Tags: kotlin, insert, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, return-value

I need to get the Auto generated ID of a record added to a ROOM database table.

Looking to answer my problem I found the following answer:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919818/how-to-return-newly-inserted-itemrow-id-using-android-room-kotlin)

But in my case is not a solution because in Compose I can't use the code:
`lifecycleScope.launch`

```
//DAO
@Insert
suspend fun addwarrantyget(warrantyEntity: WarrantyEntity): Long

//Repository
suspend fun addwarrantyget(warrantyEntity: WarrantyEntity):Long {
        return inventoryDB.warrantyDao().addwarrantyget(warrantyEntity)
    }

//viewModel
fun addwarrantyget(warranty: WarrantyEntity) =
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.addwarrantyget(warranty)
        }

//Inside Compose Fun
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val id = viewModel.addwarrantyget(warranty)
    Log.i("INSERT_ID", "Inserted ID is: $id")
}
```

As per suggestion and my understanding:

I added:

//viewModel

```
private val _newItemId = MutableStateFlow(-1L)
val newItemId: StateFlow<Long> = _newItemId

fun addwarrantyget(warranty: WarrantyEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val newId = repository.addwarrantyget(warranty)
    _newItemId.emit(newId!!)
}
```

//Compose function extract

```
Button(
                onClick = {

                    viewModel.addwarrantyget(
                       WarrantyEntity(
                            0,
                           null,
                            insn,
                            indescription,
                            null,
                           instartdateP.value,
                           inenddateP.value,
                           inprovider,
                           instartdateM.value,
                           inenddateM.value,
                           inmanufacturer
                        )
                    )
                    val newItemID by viewModel.newItemId.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
                    LaunchedEffect(newItemID) {
                        if (newItemID == -1L) return@LaunchedEffect
                        // Do what you need with the new id here
                        warrantyId.value = viewModel.newItemId
                        mToast("Warranty Added", mContext)
                    }

                    mToast("Warranty Added", mContext)

                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

            ) {
                Text(text = "Add Warranty")
            }
```

collectAsStateWithLifecycle: gives undefined reference error

warrantyId.value = viewModel.newItemId: gives Require Long Found StateFlow error

LaunchedEffect: gives @Composable invocations can only happen from the context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compose you have [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect). You won't get the id at the same place you call `viewModel.addwarrantyget(warranty)`, but you can consume the new id value from the `viewModel` as a state.

viewModel

```
private val _newItemId = MutableStateFlow(-1)
val newItemId: StateFlow<Int> = _newItemId

fun addwarrantyget(warranty: WarrantyEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val newId = repository.addwarrantyget(warranty)
    _newItemId.emit(newId)
}
```

Composable

```
    val newItemID by viewModel.newItemId.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    LaunchedEffect(newItemID) {
        if (newItemID == -1) return@LaunchedEffect
        // Do what you need with the new id here
    }
```

Note that i set  filtered out the default `newItemID` value `-1`, there are other ways to do it of course.

Edit:

Regarding `Require Long Found StateFlow` error. The `newItemID` already contains the value of the new id, you don't need to read it from the `viewModel` again.

```
mToast("New id: $newItemID", mContext)
```

Please read about [States](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) to gain better understanding of what is going on here.

About `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context...` error. As the error says, `LaunchedEffect` (as a composable function) can not be called from the `onClick` lambda, which is not a composable function. It's important to understand that consuming `newItemId` state and calling `viewModel.addwarrantyget()` are not tied together. You can put the `LaunchedEffect` to your composable screen level instead.

```
@Composable
fun YourScreen(
    viewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    // other code
    val newItemID by viewModel.newItemId.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    LaunchedEffect(newItemID) {
        if (newItemID == -1) return@LaunchedEffect
        mToast("New id: $newItemID", mContext)
    }
    // other composables
}
```

Comment: How do I add a reply? In this comment section I can't add the errors I am getting for the code that I added.

Comment: @user924223 You can edit the question.

Comment: OK. I edited the question to add more information according to the changes made.

Comment: I added dependency "implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2" for the collectAsStateWithLifecycle().  But still I do not know where I should call the LaunchEffect, because I need it to be dependent of the Click event as it has to run after the @Insert only and when then record is added.

Comment: @user924223 I don't understand what are you trying to do, can you elaborate what exactly do you want the id for?

Comment: @user924223 read about `LaunchedEffect`, it will run once on each new id.

Comment: I need the ID to use it as a reference key on a One-to-One relationship table. But the problem is that I have to create/insert record first in the dependent table.

Comment: @user924223 Something like that should never happen in a composable. Do it in the viewmodel or on database level, for example as a SQL trigger.

Comment: I found where to add the LaunchedEffect function and now is working fine.  Thank you for your help.